# Download zips on google cloud via terminal

Tags: curl, google-cloud-platform, zip

There are a large amount of zip files stored on google cloud that I would like to download, I would like a script to do this, so I do not have to do it one at a time.

I have tried to download one file using

```
curl -o https://storage.cloud.google.com/foo.zip
```

but I get an error message saying there is no URL specified.

Maybe curl is the wrong function for this?

I would like to download multiple zips hosted on google cloud that are listed in a .txt file at the same time, or one after the other.

Comment: Why don't you use `gsutil cp` command (https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/cp)?

Comment: Thanks norbjd, I was hoping to do it without using google cloud

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 solutions to download your files using the command line.

#### Use `gsutil`

You can just use `gsutil cp` command :

```
gsutil cp gs://[BUCKET_NAME]/foo.zip .
```

You can also take a look at [`gsutil rsync` command](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/rsync).

#### Use `cURL`

If using `gsutil` is not possible, you can still use `cURL` but you might need to authenticate if the object inside your bucket is not public (I assume that you do not want your objects to be public here).

From the [docs about downloading objects](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/downloading-objects) (REST APIS tab) :

```
curl -X GET \
    -H "Authorization: Bearer [OAUTH2_TOKEN]" \
    -o "[SAVE_TO_LOCATION]" \
    "https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/[BUCKET_NAME]/o/[OBJECT_NAME]?alt=media"
```

As you can see, you will need a oauth2 authorization access token to do so (see [docs on how to authenticate to Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/authentication)).

However, even if this is possible, I strongly suggest you to use the first option (`gsutil`), as stated in the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/downloading-objects) :

> To easily download all objects in a bucket or subdirectory, use the `gsutil cp` command.